# How to mysqldump some tables without data?

Tags: mysql, no-data

I already have one solution here:
first, dump the structure with data of all tables excluding some tables;
then, dump the structure of those excluded tables without data.

For example:

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword database_name --ignore-table=sils.zone > test.sql;
mysqldump database_name table_name -d >> test.sql;
```

But is there any better way to solve this with only one dump statement?

Comment: unfortunately `--no-data` is available as a global switch only, so I can't think of any other solution than your two-step approach